# How to create an sqlconnection in a class with c# to use in all form?

Tags: c#

1. Create sqlserver connection in class
2. call connection class to use all form.

I want to create SQLServer connection in class with C# to use all forms.

Hereabout code of connection in class file

```
public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

public string conStr;

public SQL2(string conStr)
{
    try
    {
        Con.ConnectionString = conStr;
        Con.Open();
        Com.Connection = Con;
        Com.CommandTimeout = 3600;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public bool IsConnection()
{
    Boolean st;

    if (Con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        st=true;
    }
    else
    {
        st = false;
    }

    return st;
}
```

Can give me full example code?

Comment: Ok, please, try to explain it once again and use English this time. What is your problem?

Comment: Close your connections the moment you are done with them.  Don't hold them open in a class like this.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a factory that you use to use to create a connection:

```
using(var connection = databaseConenctionFactory.Create())
{
    // then do want you want here
}
```

As LarsTech mentioned you don't want to keep open connections.  Open/Use/Close.  The `using` syntax is rather useful here as it takes care of all the unnecessary fluff.  So once you are in a habit of using `using` you will not run into any weird behaviour in production systems.

There is quite a bit around implementing something like this so you could do some research.  You could make use of the ADO Provider Factories and use `IDbConnection` instead of a specific implementation to abstract you implemetation.

You could also usse dependency injection to get to you factory/factories.

So choose your poison :)

Comment: It might be helpful to point out, that by using the 'using-statement', the Dispose() method of the object (in this case connection) is called. This method usually cleans up resources, like closing connections /files. You can (and should) use the using statement on any object that inherits from IDisposable