# c sharp return object from function

Tags: c#, mysql, database

im facing a problem , when  i creat my own class i want to create Mysql connection function and i want to use it inside all my forms i do this

program.cs

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
public class testing
    {
        public string fahadt="Hello Class";




        public  void conncting()
        {


            MySqlConnection connection;
            string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=taxi";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            try
            {

                connection.Open();

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
               // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
```

and in my form

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            testing fahad = new testing();
            try
            {
                dataGridView1.Show();
                fahad.conncting();

                // here is error under fahad.conncting.createcommand();
                MySqlCommand cmd = fahad.conncting.CreateCommand();
                //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM  ocms_visitors WHERE `id`='"+textBox4.Text+"'";
               // MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //textBox4.Text = adap.id;

               // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
               // adap.Fill(ds);

               // dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                //MessageBox.Show("Yes Mysql Connection is Working Now  !");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

i dont know how i can do it im very new = C#

please help me and also i have another q should i use 
using .... in class and form or Enough in class ?

thanks

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372713/how-to-create-an-sqlconnection-in-a-class-with-c-sharp-to-use-in-all-form also try doing a google search 
>
type this in to google C# stackoverflow make sqlconnection object that's used in all forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `MySqlConnection`

Modify your function to:

```
    public  MySqlConnection conncting()
    {


        MySqlConnection connection;
        string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=taxi";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        try
        {

            connection.Open();
            return connection;

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            return null;
           // MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but how i can used in the form 

MySqlCommand cmd = fahad.conncting().CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM  ocms_visitors WHERE `id`='3'";
                MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

Comment: What error are you getting. For me the code in your comment should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, it looks to me like you have already created the connection you were looking for.  Next steps for you would be to learn about the SqlCommand Class.

For reference/edification, try this [link](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet), and happy coding!

Comment: how can program for me Mysql Class ? cos  i tryed many time all not working

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to return a connection from your `conncting()` method?

```
    public MySqlConnection conncting()
    {
        string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=taxi";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
```

To answer your second question, yes, using `using {..}` blocks is a good idea for `IDisposable` instances whenever possible.  This includes connections, commands, data adapters, etc.  The following might be a reasonable pattern:

```
    using (MySqlConnection conn = fahad.conncting())
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from table", conn))
    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
        // do something with datatable
    }
```